# Difference between comparison and addition

Tags: fpga

Is addition(+) operation more complex than comparison operation (>), both in integer as well as floating point arithmetic? I would appreciate answer in the context of both microprocessor- and FPGA-based systems.

My thought:
I think comparison and addition are the same thing when we talk about microprocessor-based systems because comparison a>b can be solved by checking the sign bit of (a-b), i.e, an addition operation. But, in the context of FPGA-based systems, I guess the complexity of comparison operator can be reduced?

Comment: How is this C++ related? In the language (and for integral types) they are just basic primitive operations. The language does not consider how complex they are in any particular architecture

Comment: How are you defining complexity?  On an FPGA, I guess you're talking about resource usage.  On a microprocessor, I guess you're talking about cycle count?  Either way, this is probably off-topic, and should be on http://electronics.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: so that I can have an opinion of C++ developers (for desktop PCs) as well. I know they are not very much concerned with this thing but just wanted to know how things are in microprocessors for desktop PCs.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Oh my bad. I searched for hardware stackexchange but it turned out to be that there is no such thing as hardware dot stackexchange so i posted it here! I didn't know about electronics.stackexchange.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: My question can be put as follows: If I construct a special hardware for comparison and don't perform it using the sign bit of (a-b)>0, will it save me cycle count (microprocessor-based systems) or resource usage(fpga-based systems).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah I overlooked that part! I take off the C++ tag from the question.

Comment: Maybe http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals ?

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks! Its an amazing reference. It says the following:

1. "Floating point comparisons are slow unless the Pentium-II or later instruction set is enabled."

2. "Simple integer operations such as addition,
subtraction, comparison, bit operations and shift operations take only one clock cycle on
most microprocessors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison is a bit "simpler" for integers, because we only need to compare each bit from msb to lsb (without a carry bit, which is needed by addition). In terms of complexity, both are O(log n) though.

But I doubt you can actually measure this small difference in terms of resource usage (logic slices or power consumption).

Comment: So, its of no use if I convert an algorithm based on additions to an algorithm based on comparisons?

Comment: Why didn't you just ask your real question as your question - about how to optimize something?

Comment: @tenfour In my opinion, it is always better to ask the specific question on these forums instead of putting it in generality. There will be many answers to 'How to optimize?' whereas the only thing I wanted to know whether 'an addition more complex than comparison' in current systems.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, comparison could be quicker you just need to compare each bits and that can be done in parallel.
This comparison is done in two stages, one wich compares all bits, and a second one which check if one bits is on. (it's technically (a0^b0)|(a1^b1)|...(an^bn). 
All the ai^bi can be done at the same time. That should be O(log(n))

However, for the addition, you need to propagate the carry from each bit to the other so you end up in O(n).